# Subclassing Formatter to accept Swift Structs in Swift 3.2 and later

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, foundation, nsformatter

I have a need to format in several places the same piece of data to a human readable format. However, I have several frameworks that represent this information in different ways. To avoid duplication of this code, I have a `Formatter` for formatting a common representation of this data. Any frameworks that want to use this human readable representation can have their data declare conformance to a `Protocol` (usually in an extension) that converts their own representation to the common `Struct` used by the formatter.

This worked as I'd expect in Swift 3. However, in Swift 3.2 and higher, the cast to the `Protocol` inside `string(for obj:)` fails. I don't know if this is a deliberate change, or a bug. In this example:

```
import Foundation

struct Widget {
    let frobberCount: Int
    let tweakerCount: Int
}

protocol WidgetRepresentable {
    var widgetRepresentation: Widget { get }
}

extension Widget: WidgetRepresentable {
    var widgetRepresentation: Widget {
        return self
    }
}

class WidgetFormatter: Formatter {
    override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
        guard let widget = obj as? WidgetRepresentable else { // This cast fails
            return nil
        }

        return string(from: widget)
    }

    func string(from widgetRepresentable: WidgetRepresentable) -> String {
        let widget = widgetRepresentable.widgetRepresentation
        return "\(widget.frobberCount) frobber(s), \(widget.tweakerCount) tweaker(s)"
    }
}

let formatter = WidgetFormatter()
let widget = Widget(frobberCount: 2, tweakerCount: 4)

formatter.string(for: widget) // Returns nil. Expected 2 frobber(s), 4 tweaker(s)
formatter.string(from: widget) // Correctly returns 2 frobber(s), 4 tweaker(s)
```

As a workaround, the issue goes away if I do any of the following:

- Use the convenience `string(from:)` function, instead of `string(for:)` overridden from `Formatter`.
- Have `WidgetFormatter` no longer subclass `Formatter` (removing the `override` annotation from the `string(for:)` function)
- Have `Widget` be a `class`, along with whatever is conforming to `WidgetRepresentable`.

Those last 2 points are making me wonder whether this is an issue with Objective-C bridging between `NSFoundation` and `Foundation` in Swift.

Is there an issue with my methodology here, or is this a bug in Swift? If it's the latter, I'll file a radar.

Comment: It *is* a bug, as explained in the "duplicate". In your case, `guard let widget = obj as AnyObject as? WidgetRepresentable` is the workaround.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you very much!